# Solving equation with an exponential

Tags: math, equation, exp

I want to solve for `x`:

```
1 = a b e^(b(x-c))
```

That's where I'm stuck.  I want to solve for `x`, and all the other letters are constants.  I've forgotten how to solve that equation with the embedded "`b(x-c)`" for `x`.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a purely algebraic problem, and doesn’t require any programming.

Comment: Please try https://math.stackexchange.com. It's unclear how writing code is supposed to help solve the problem.

Comment: Am I right to understand that your question is just *"How do I solve for `x` the equation `1 = a b e^(b(x-c))`?"* And actually has nothing to do with line slopes whatsoever and that the first 80% of your post have nothing to do with the actual question? If not, feel free to roll back my edit.

Answer (score 3):

Use logarithm

```
 e^(b(x-c)) = 1/(ab)
 ln(e^(b(x-c))) = ln(1/(ab))
 b*(x-c) = -ln(a*b)
 x-c = -ln(a*b)/b
 x = c - ln(a*b)/b
```